# Google OR Tools OnlyEnforceIf

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools, cp-sat

I got a problem for using onlyenforceif to set up constraint.

work[employee , shift , day] is the BoolVar indicating the scheduling status for each staff each day.

I would like to set a limit that for staff who worked on shift A on day 1 and shift B on day 2 then they are not allowed to work on shift c on day 3. But the code does not work.

Could you please give me some hint how to revise it. Many thanks!

```
#Constraint 9 - M -> N -> D shift pattern
#if day n == "N" and day n+1 == 'O' then day n+2 <> 'M'
for e in range(num_employees):
    for d in range(0 , num_days-2):
      model.Add(work[e,2, d+2] == 0).OnlyEnforceIf([work[e,4, d] , work[e,1, d+1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

So it should work

otherwise, you can go full Boolean

```
model.AddBoolOr([work[e,4, d].Not() , work[e,1, d+1].Not(), work[e,2, d+2].Not()])
```